# How to validate file names from a HTTP request in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

I have a node.js application that exposes an API to delete images from a assets directory.

So a user can perform a `DELETE` request and send the specified image to delete, this is how it is being handled currently:

```
const assetsPath = '/assets'

deleteFile(file: string) {
  fs.unlink(`${assetsPath}/${file}`, (err) => {})
}
```

The problem with that is that a user can submit a request like so:
`http://server.com?fileName=../../some_personal_file.exe`
and it would delete a file outside of the assets directory

How can I prevent that? I guess checking for `fileName.includes('../')` is just a partial solution

Comment: This attack vector is normally referred to as directory/path traversal, Node publish information on how to mitigate this: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/file-system/security/introduction/#preventing-directory-traversal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js have [published information](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/file-system/security/introduction/#preventing-directory-traversal) on how to mitigate this attack (referred to as [Path Traversal](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal)).

Taken from that advisory, you can use the `path` module to ensure that this operation is safe, like so:

```js
const path = require('path');
const assetsPath = '/assets';

deleteFile(file: string) {
    let deletePath = path.join(assetsPath, file);
    if (deletePath.indexOf(assetsPath) === 0) {
        fs.unlink(deletePath, err => {});
    } else {
        // Display an error to the user somehow
    }
}
```